# Bottom of text cut off in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, text

I was looking at a friends website and noticed most of the text has the bottom cut off but only when viewing in chrome. I poked around in the css but couldn't seem to find the issue.

Can anyone help me out?

The site is http://www.customcasez.com/

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: strange, this is what i see on mine. http://i.imgur.com/2vRxPdP.jpg

Comment: @tracebell2000 I see it too

Comment: it looks like the font is causing that problem. try replacing it with with some similar font or try to download it from another source.

Comment: Huh...this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/SNFVu16.jpg

Comment: this is how it looks at my place (in chrome) http://i.imgur.com/zruY3o3.png

Comment: Interesting, but I just saw the google fonts page too. So it does appear to be the font but I wonder why Paul isn't having the same issue.

Comment: maybe its chrome version. mine is Version 31.0.1650.57 m (on windows 8)

Comment: I am also using 31.0.1650.57 but on Windows 7 x64

Comment: I am using 31.0.1650.57 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue exists here, [Bubbler+One font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Bubbler+One#charset) (at least for me in chrome).
here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lVK.jpg) about how it looks at my place.

So, I guess the issue is not with your website but with the font itself.

Try replacing the font-family with some similar font or try to download it from another source

Comment: Yeah I have the same issue on that page as well. Will try another font, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Text in input box looked fine in Firefox however it was cut off from bottom in Chrome.
Check with padding of the input box, it is smartly managed in Firefox but not in Chrome!
I gave padding as `padding:0px 6px;` (or whatever you intend to give!)